# Can I track the CPU load that IPTABLES firewall is causing?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

Since IPTABLES is a software based firewall, I am wondering if it is possible to log the exact load it is causing, cpu cycles, etc.

On a small system I am sure it is trivial. But how about with thousands of rules?

Looking in TOP and PS, this seems to elude me, so it must be a kernel level component?

Can it be isolated and monitored/logged?

**eta:** *for clarity, on modern linux, iptables is not a visible process or daemon so it cannot be seen for example with `ps aux` and I am at a loss for how to isolate it from the kernel otherwise*

Comment: The `sy%` in `top` tells you the percent of time the system is spending in kernel mode, as opposed to user mode.

Comment: @ultrasawblade - that's a start but far from exactly monitoring iptables, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The actual processing of the iptables rules is done in softirq context so changes in the `si%` value in `top` (or `%soft` in `mpstat`) should give a hint about how much load it causes. If you want more details you could use the `ftrace` function tracer (see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt for more info) to log the calls to the respective kernel functions and measure the latency. However, this requires support in the kernel, i.e. specific kernel config options.